# How do I show progress to the user when fetching data via a series of webservice calls in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, .net-3.5

I have a asp.net control (.net 3.5) that makes a series of calls to a webservice to get data from a database which is then put into gridviews. As each database query takes a few seconds I do it in a series of calls rather than all in one go, otherwise it would time out.

The page doesn't seem to render until all the data is returned. How can I show progress to the user as each call is made to give them confidence that something is actually happening?

The grids contain financial data. The user selects a month and year and then presses a button which starts this sequences of webservice calls. So this is usually happening in a postback (although the page initially renders with the data for the current month and year, if any).

I've come across [UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386573%28VS.90%29.aspx)s. Would this make each table render as the data is filled in?

Edit: here's what I've tried so far using Sunny's suggestion

.ascx file

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ProgressTemplate>
      UpdatePanel1 updating...
    </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress2" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
    <ProgressTemplate>
      UpdatePanel2 updating...
    </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>

<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblOB"></asp:Label><asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <contenttemplate>
<h3><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblT1"></asp:Label></h3>
<asp:GridView runat="server" id="gridT1">
</asp:GridView>

    </contenttemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
    <contenttemplate>
<h3><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblT2"></asp:Label></h3>
<asp:GridView runat="server" id="gridT2">
<Columns>
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    </contenttemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

.ascx.vb file:

```
 (Pseudo code)
 Call webservice for table 1
 gridT1.datasource = table 1 data from webserivce
 gridT1.DataBind()
 lblT1.text = heading

 Call webservice for table 2
 gridT2.datasource = tabld 2 data from webserivce
 gridT2.DataBind()
 lblT12text = heading
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can use Ajax loader or UpdateProgress Ajax control here.

Comment: I've put a couple of UpdatePanels together with corresponding UpdateProgress sections, but I don't see the contents of the UpdateProgress sections while the page is working.

Comment: I also made one application in which i have lots of update panels but UpdateProgress work there fine can you provide me some aspx code ?